# Cantidad de consultas efectuadas por un usuario a lo largo del año

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Buen dia,

Estoy tratando de obtener la cantidad de registros ingresados por un usuario a una tabla a lo largo del año.

Éste es el query que estoy tirando y el resultado que está arrojando

```
ID_USUARIO  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12
4651934     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
4651934     0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
```

Resultado esperado:

```
ID_USUARIO  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12
4651934     0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0


SELECT ID_USUARIO 
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 1, 1, 0)) M1,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 2, 1, 0)) M2,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 3, 1, 0)) M3,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 4, 1, 0)) M4,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 5, 1, 0)) M5,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 6, 1, 0)) M6,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 7, 1, 0)) M7,
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 8, 1, 0)) M8,    
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 9, 1, 0)) M9,    
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 10, 1, 0)) M10,    
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 11, 1, 0)) M11,    
    SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE), 12, 1, 0)) M12 
FROM UPLOAD_FILES 
  WHERE UPLOAD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30-08-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')  
  AND FUENTE = 1 
  AND ID_USUARIO = 4651934
  GROUP BY ID_USUARIO, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE)
  ORDER BY ID_USUARIO ;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara bien que base de datos estas usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas agrupando por usuario, mes, y eso provoca que para cada mes tengas una fila distinta para el mismo usuario. Si a tu query actual le agregas `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM UPLOAD_DATE)` en el `select`, vas a ver que cada registro tiene un mes distinto, y por lo tanto no va a agrupar todo el resultado en una sola fila.

Para solucionarlo facil, podes envolver todo tu select actual y hacer:

```
SELECT ID_USUARIO,
    sum(M1),
    sum(M2),
    etc...
FROM (tu query actual)
GROUP BY ID_USUARIO
```